# Riesz representation theorem in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

My question is about functionals on $W_{1,p}(\Omega)$ spaces, $\Omega$ is contained in $\mathbb R^n$

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to characterize all linear functionals on the above space.

Is there any version of Riesz representation theorem in general Banach space?

Comment: Although, you cannot achieve that in $W_{1,p}$, there are Riesz-like results for $\mathcal{L}_p$ and $\ell_p$ spaces. 
Let $X=\mathcal{L}_p(\Omega, \mathscr{F},\mathrm{P})$. According to D.S. Bridges, *Foundations of real and abstract analysis*, Springer, 1998, p. 202, we may identify all linear continuous functionals $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ by elements $\tilde{f}\in X^*$ such that $f(x) = \int_\Omega \tilde{f}(\omega)x(\omega)\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega)$.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Riesz representation theorem that would say something about a general Banach space $X$. For such a space, it is customary to denote the space of all continuous linear functionals as $X^*$, which is called the dual space of $X$. One can try to give a concrete description of the elements of $X^*$, but the success depends on what $X$ is. For many function spaces the structure of the dual is already known, as searching for "dual of ... space" will show you.

Specifically, the dual space of the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}$  is described by Theorem 3.9 of the book *Sobolev spaces* by Adams.

> For every $L\in (W^{1,p}(\Omega))^*$ there exist elements $v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\in L^{p'}(\Omega)$ (where $n$ is the dimension and $p'=p/(p-1)$) such that 
>   $$L(u) = \int_\Omega \left(uv_0+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_k} v_k\right)$$

The structure of the dual is nicer if one restricts the attention to $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, because integration by parts does not produce boundary terms then. The dual of $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is naturally identified with $W^{-1,p'}(\Omega)$, a Sobolev space of negative order of smoothness.

---

See also: [Dual space of the sobolev spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246735/dual-space-of-the-sobolev-spaces)

Comment: Do you know any space of functions $X$ such that $$X^\star=W^{1,1}(\Omega)?$$

Comment: There is no such $X$. A separable dual space has the Radon-Nikodym property. And $W^{1,1}$ contains an isomorphic copy of $L^1$, it's essentially a direct sum of some copies of $L^1$. And $L^1$  fails the Radon-Nikodym property.

Comment: Are there any practical examples for such $v_k$ for given functionals? And how can I check whether this representation is unique?