# Why and how can I represent weak werivatives as functionals in sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

How can I show for some suitable $f \in L^p$, that $\Delta f \in (W^{1,p^\prime}_0)^*$

Maybe we can solve this with the answer of

[Riesz representation theorem in Sobolev spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170541/riesz-representation-theorem-in-sobolev-spaces)