# Characterization of $H^{-1}(U)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof of characterization of $H^{-1}(U)$ as in Evan's Partial Differential equations. My questions is different to that of [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72508/characterization-of-the-h-1-norm-in-evanss-pde-book).

In the theorem regarding the same, it is stated that

Assume $f \in H^{-1}$ then there exist $f^0$, $f^1$,....$f^n$ in $L^2(U)$ such that

\begin{equation}
<f,v> = \int_{U}f^0v + \sum\limits_{i=1}^nf^iv_{x_i}dx \hspace10mm (v \in H^1_0)\nonumber
\end{equation}

Here $⟨⋅,⋅⟩$ denotes the dual pairing of $H^{−1}$ and $H^{1}_0$.

In the proof, he states that if $f \in H^{−1}(U)$, then by Riesz representation theorem, there exists a unique function $u \in H^{1}_0(U)$, for all $v \in H^{1}_0(U)$ such that

\begin{equation}
<f,v> = \int_UDu \cdot Dv + uvdx \nonumber. 
\end{equation}
And hence it establishes the statement (i).

Following things confuse me:

1. If we are not supposed to identify $H^{−1}(U)$ with $H^{1}_0(U)$, how can we use the riesz representation theorem?
2. Since we have $L^2(U) \subset H^{−1}(U)$ how does that fit with the theorem. That is how does the fact that in general the inner product of $H^1_0$ might not be valid for a function in $L^2(U)$, which is not considered while invoking the Riesz theorem for the characterisation of an $f$ in $H^{-1}(U)$ in the above proof, fit with Riesz representation theorem?
3. How can we show any $f$, as defined above, can be attained in the limit as
   \begin{equation}
   <f,v> = \int_U u_nvdx \hspace2mm  \forall v \in H^1_0(U)
   \end{equation}
   for some sequence   $u_n$ in $L^2(U)$, since we know $L^2(U)$ is dense in $H^{−1}(U)$.
4. Lastly, what would we lose out on if we identified $H^{1}_0(U)$ with it's dual and what part of the Riesz representation theorem leaves room for some flexibility regarding identifying or not identifying $H^{1}_0(U)$ with it's dual.

Comment: The proof of Evans shows that $H^{-1}$ can be identified with $H_0^1$. So, what is your question?

Comment: $H^{-1}$ is by definition the dual space of $H^1_0$, and so Riesz says there is a canonical isomorphism between them.  "Identifying" them would be pretending they are really the same space and the isomorphism is the identity map - Evans is not doing that.

Comment: Is this comment for me @NateEldredge?

Comment: @Tomás: Not really, unless you want it to be :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge, nah, at least my conception of identification here a little bit more broad. By the way, do you understood his question? I think I am little bit lost here.

Comment: [The dual space of the Sobolev space $H_0^1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700699/) is a similar question to yours. I think it answers at least item 2.

Comment: Thanks, that most of the comments make sense with respect to my question 1 and 2. I would appreciate any insight on the other two.